# Swiper pre load spinner (loader) not removed when the image url is updated

Tags: angular, rxjs, swiper.js

I'm using swiper with angular to display a list of images, with lazy loading enabled.

On the first load of the page everything works as expected, but when the image url is updated dynamically, the swiper refreshes, and the spinner stays displayed.
Resizing the browser window or clicking the next slide button fixes it.

My swipepr setting:

```
<swiper
  class="image-carousel"
  [slidesPerView]="1"
  [navigation]="navigation"
  [pagination]="pagination ? { clickable: true } : false"
  [lazy]="lazyLoad"
  [preloadImages]="false"
  [watchOverflow]="true">
  <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let photoUrl of imageUrls">
    <img data-src="{{photoUrl}}" class="swiper-lazy slide-image" />
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
  </ng-template>
</swiper>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the img should be like this

```
<img [attr.data-src]="photoUrl" [src]="photoUrl">
```